# How to create line breaks in the description file in RAML?

Tags: field, raml

I have a field in RAML that requires a very long description. Is there a way to break it up into multiple lines?

Example:

"description": "This is a very long string"

I would like it to render as:

"description": "This is
a very long string."

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `|` to break a long line into multiple parts :-

```
 post:
    description: |
      Creates a new account. Some **bold** text here. More text. Need to fill the line, so make it longer still. Hooray!
      Line two Starts here
```

ref:- https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html/blob/master/examples/example.raml

Another option is using `!` and `\n` to break the line :-

```
  post:
        description: !
          "Creates a new account. Some **bold** text here. More text. Need to fill the line, so make it longer still. Hooray!\n
          Line two Starts here"
```

Please note here the description should be under `""` double quotes

Comment: Thanks Anirban, but I'm talking about the description of one of the fiels in a schema.

Comment: In your question, you clearly mentioned :- "**I have a field in RAML that requires a very long description.**"

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. I'm very new to this, so the questions I pose might not be clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
...  
  description:
    1st line<br>
    2nd line<br>
    3rd line<br>
```

or

```rb
...  
  description: 1st line<br>2nd line<br>3rd line<br>
```

just as follows:
[raw raml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxEHe.jpg)
[produced html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCeZy.jpg)

Comment: If `<br>` does not work, trying adding a single whitespace before it. Example: `foobar <br>` rather than `foobar<br>`.